# Collection with Type as parameter in Custom Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have a custom annotation as below:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface CustomAnnotation {
  String description();
  Class type;
}
```

and I use it as below:

```
class MyClass {

  @CustomAnnotation(description="Some Description", type=MyClass.class)
  public void someMethod() {
  }
}
```

However, I want the ability to specify a List of MyClass as "type", something like below:

```
class MyClass {

  @CustomAnnotation(description="Some Description", type=List<MyClass>.class)
  public void someMethod() {
  }
}
```

I see it isn't possible. What I can do is, add another attribute to the annotation to specify if the type is a collection or not, but is there any other better alternative? I believe there isn't, but asking just in case if there is any hope.